# Declaring function as static in header file causes declared but not defined error

Tags: c++, static

Suppose I have a header file like this

```
namespace a
{
    static void fun();
}
```

and I have its definition in source file

```
namespace a
{
    void fun()
    {
    }
}
```

This header file may be used in these files' own project or in several other projects. I get the the fun() function declared but not defined error. I don't understand why. But if I remove static from declaration, it works!

Comment: You're *declaring* a static function in every translation unit including that header, but only *defining* it in *one*. And your surprised you get unresolved references because.. ?

Comment: @WhozCraig how do I make it so that other translation units will also recognizes the only definition I wrote for it? I want all the translation units that includes this header file will get that single definition. Thanks.

Comment: Then either don't make it static (they all get to use the *single* definition, implemented in *one* translation unit), or make it static *and* move the implementation to the header as well (i.e. no source file, all header), at which point everyone gets their own *copy* of the function. honestly though, if you're doing that you should seriously consider *why* you need to, because rare is the case you actually do.

Comment: I will remove the static from the function declaration. Nice explanation in both of the comments. Thanks:-) Maybe you can make an answer and I could mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: no need. Khnle said everything I did with about 90% fewer words =P

Comment: Well I understood yours :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The static keyword in this case means that the scope of the function fun() is limited to the file, i.e. it has the file scope.  Removing the static, it has a global scope, but only within the namespace.